# SOQL with GMT datetime in process-config.xml

Tags: soql

I’m having problems with this statement **IN BATCH** -> process-config.xml (the SOQL runs just fine running it by hand in the Data Loader Utility)

I’m thinking there’s some sort of special character maybe that delimits GMT dates in SOQL? do I need to "escape" any ">" or "<" in the SOQL (for batch?)

```
                          <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, Agent_Code__c,CL_Closed__c,PL_Closed_Auto__c,PL_Closed_Home__c,md_Status__c,Created_By_Name__c,CreatedDate,Actual_Last_Modified_By__c,Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c FROM Account WHERE (CREATEDDATE >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z AND CREATEDDATE <= TODAY) or (Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z AND Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c <= TODAY)"/>
```

I was under the impression that it was a Java Bean definition issue, but now I can tell it’s definitely the SOQL.

Version of the Salesforce Data Loader is the most recent (v49.0.0).

Here's the non-confidential parts of the                               
Export Account FULLDELTA to CSV

```
<!-- Change the next line to match the path to your key file -->
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="c:\forcedotcom_dataloader\dataloader_win\bin\Key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.useBulkApi" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="10000"/>
    
<!--  Change the next line to match the Salesforce object you wish to extract -->
        <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>

<!-- Change the SOQL statement in the next line to get the fields you want from the above obect -->
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, Agent_Code__c,CL_Closed__c,PL_Closed_Auto__c,PL_Closed_Home__c,md_Status__c,Created_By_Name__c,CreatedDate,Actual_Last_Modified_By__c,Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c FROM Account WHERE (CREATEDDATE >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z AND CREATEDDATE <= TODAY) or (Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z AND Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c <= TODAY)"/>
            
        <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            
<!-- Change the next line to the path and file that you wish to save the extract to.  -->
        <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="\\nass1\UW_Workstation\DEV SalesForce Extracts\Agent - Account.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Milliseconds are not supported in SOQL. So your SOQL should use `2020-09-01T00:00:00Z`.

See [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

Comment: NO difference, FAILS in BATCH (process-conf.xml)  using your format just the same.  always worked fine interactively, in EITHER format. Also, I tried "LAST_N_WEEKS:n" which again, works fine interactively, but NOT in batch. Only the simplest of SOQL works in batch, like: Select Id, Agent_Code__c,CL_Closed__c,PL_Closed_Auto__c,PL_Closed_Home__c,md_Status__c,Created_By_Name__c,CreatedDate,Actual_Last_Modified_By__c,Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c FROM Account WHERE CREATEDDATE = TODAY or Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c = TODAY   (this is v49.0.0 of the DataLoader?)

Comment: so the $1M question is, why does this work interactively and NOT in batch? Select Id, Agent_Code__c,CL_Closed__c,PL_Closed_Auto__c,PL_Closed_Home__c,md_Status__c,Created_By_Name__c,CreatedDate,Actual_Last_Modified_By__c,Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c FROM Account WHERE (CREATEDDATE >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z AND CREATEDDATE <= TODAY) or (Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c >= 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z AND Actual_Last_Modified_Date__c <= TODAY)

Comment: Could you edit your original question with the error you are getting?

Comment: This is interesting.., I'm getting NO debug messages/errors. I've CUT OUT all of the confidential stuff in my <bean> (below). I'm a self taught newbie on the Dataloader (with about 12 working just fine already). Here's my <bean> out of process-conf.xml... (to big for comment) posted <bean> pasted into original question, the bean

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "& g t ;" or "& l t ;" (without the spaces I have here so it doesn't show those symbols here in the ANSWER, -> for **greater than** and **less than**), otherwise this parser is interpreting it as being XML (versus a SOQL string value for a property)